# Obtener respuesta de USSD Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Actualmente me encuentro ante el problema de obtener la respuesta de una llamada USSD  , eh investigado un poco y encontre que recien desde la API 26 osea OREON , Android saco una api llamada 
TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback.html

que el codigo para ejecutarlo es asi

```
      TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    manager.sendUssdRequest(USSD, new TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveUssdResponse(TelephonyManager telephonyManager, String request, CharSequence response) {
            super.onReceiveUssdResponse(telephonyManager, request, response);


            Toast.makeText(Login.this,  response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceiveUssdResponseFailed(TelephonyManager telephonyManager, String request, int failureCode) {
            super.onReceiveUssdResponseFailed(telephonyManager, request, failureCode);
            Toast.makeText(Login.this,  request, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Handler());
```

aunque esto como como dije es para api 26 , estaria necesitando algo que sirva desde 4.1 en adelante , desde ya agradesco cualquier ayuda

Comment: Hola Bruno! que es lo que deseas en realidad, no veo lo especifique tu pregunta, deseas unicamente ejecutar el USSD ?

Comment: Hola Jorge! , quisiera poder realizar una peticion USSD en el backend de la aplicacion y poder recibir la respuesta de la llamada ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto puedes realizar un método que funcione tanto con API 26 o mayor y también con versiones anteriores a API 26:

```
private final static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE = 123;

private void requestUSSD(String USSD){

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
        return;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { //API >= 26
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        manager.sendUssdRequest(USSD, new TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveUssdResponse(TelephonyManager telephonyManager, String request, CharSequence response) {
                super.onReceiveUssdResponse(telephonyManager, request, response);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onReceiveUssdResponse()" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceiveUssdResponseFailed(TelephonyManager telephonyManager, String request, int failureCode) {
                super.onReceiveUssdResponseFailed(telephonyManager, request, failureCode);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onReceiveUssdResponseFailed()" + request, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Handler());
    }else{      //API < 26
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" +USSD));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }

}

//Detecta si los permisos fueron concedidos (android 6.0+)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE : {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // PERMISO CONCEDIDO!
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se tienen permisos CALL_PHONE!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**[La obtención de respuesta únicamente es soportada por API 26 o mayor.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#sendUssdRequest(java.lang.String,%20android.telephony.TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback,%20android.os.Handler))**

---

> Es muy importante tener en cuenta que los USSD codes no son soportados en
>   todos los dispositivos, incluso algunos son bloqueados por el carrier,
>   por lo que puedes tener el mensaje "invalid MMI code".

Comment: Por lo que te refieres que si es menor de 26 no podre recibir la respuesta ? , se que no hay una api propia , eh estado mirando eh intentando realizar estos https://habrahabr.ru/post/234425/ y  http://umeshisran4android.blogspot.com.uy/2015/11/how-to-readparse-ussd-messages.html aunque no eh tenido exito

Comment: Si se puede, el método lo realiza con su método adecuado para versiones API menores a 26.

Comment: lo que hace el metodo para menor es llamar al ussd pero no puedo recibir el callback de la llamada verdad?

Comment: escribí en la respuesta : "La obtención de respuesta únicamente es soportada por API 26 o mayor.".

Comment: Impecable , Gracias Jorge , como siempre un capo!

Comment: Jorge , ya pude encontrar una forma de recibir el callback de una llamada USSD con android  desde 4.1 en adelante , lo realice atravez del servicio de accecibilidad

Comment: Agrega tu respuesta aquí por favor., me gustaría saber lo que comntas y la marcas como correcta.

Comment: Hay te deje la respuesta de todo lo que utilize para obtener la respuesta del ussd en android menores a Oreon

Answer (score 0):

La forma de resolver fue usando el servicio de Accesibilidad

primero cree la clase de servicio

```
public class XXXX extends AccessibilityService {

    public static String TAG = "XXXX";

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent");
        String text = event.getText().toString();

        if (event.getClassName().equals("android.app.AlertDialog")) {
            performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);

            Log.d(TAG, text);
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.times.ussd.action.REFRESH");
            intent.putExtra("message", text);
            Globals.setTEXT(text);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
        info.packageNames = new String[]{"com.android.phone"};
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
        setServiceInfo(info);
    }


}
```

En el Manifest

```
 <service android:name=".XXXX"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/config_service" /> // created below
    </service>
```

en la clase donde se quiere realizar la solicitud

```
String USSD = Uri.encode("*") + "611" + Uri.encode("#");
 requestUSSD(USSD);
```

metodo:

```
private void requestUSSD(String USSD){

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Login.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
        return;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { //API >= 26
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        manager.sendUssdRequest(USSD, new TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveUssdResponse(TelephonyManager telephonyManager, String request, CharSequence response) {
                super.onReceiveUssdResponse(telephonyManager, request, response);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onReceiveUssdResponse()" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onReceiveUssdResponseFailed(TelephonyManager telephonyManager, String request, int failureCode) {
                super.onReceiveUssdResponseFailed(telephonyManager, request, failureCode);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onReceiveUssdResponseFailed()" + request, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Handler());
    }else{      //API < 26
        startService(new Intent(this, XXXX.class));
        dailNumber("*611#");
    }

}
```

dailNumber :

```
 private void dailNumber(String s) {
    String USSD = Uri.encode("*") + "611" + Uri.encode("#");
    startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + USSD)));
}
```

config_service :

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:description="@string/desc"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
android:packageNames="com.times.ussd"
android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.accessibility.ServiceSettingsActivity" />
```

Importante una vez instalada la aplicacion es ir a Configuracion - Accecibildad - buscar la aplicacion y darle permisos de accecibilidad